# We're all Greek here

Tags: riddle, word

Remove my first, and I'm still Greek.

Remove my last, and I'm associated with Jimmy 'The Greek'

Remove my middle, and you might have one in Ancient Greek.

What word am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you are

> Beta, a greek letter

Remove my first, and I'm still Greek.

> eta, a greek letter

Remove my last, and I'm associated with Jimmy 'The Greek'

> bet (he was a bettor)

Remove my middle, and you might have one in Ancient Greek.

> B.A.  you may have a Bachelor of Arts in Ancient Greek

Comment: All but the last explanation is what I was thinking.

Comment: @HerbWolfe modified the last answer